# lineHeight in react-native Text component not working as expected

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have a standard Text component in my code.

```
 <Text style={Styles.headerText} numberOfLines={2}>
   {this.props.config.mag_screen_title}
 </Text>
```

I am specifying lineHeight in the style.

```
headerText: {
  fontFamily: fonts.gilroyBold,
  fontSize: 24,
  lineHeight: 25,
},
```

However, the display does not respect my lineHeight settings. The displayed lineHeight in inspector comes as 31 pixels.

[image]

The spec with the correct lineHeight looks like this.

[image]

Comment: I did some more research and found that displayed line height is always 6px more than specified line height. For font size of 24px, if I don't specify line height, line height is 30px. If I specify a line height of 25px, line height displayed is 31px. If I specified a line height of 19px, the displayed line height is 25px.

Comment: Helpful if you could attach the link also or give source ref.

Answer (score 2):

It may be because of using nesting Text. If you want to change lineHeight, you must change style of the parent Text like this:

```
<Text style={ {lineHeight: 25} }>
  Parent Text <Text style={ {fontSize: 24} }>Child Text</Text>
</Text>
```